# HttpURLConnection does not respond as expected

Tags: java, php, httpurlconnection

I have created a free-hosting account where I have been given a free domain name that I can access using any browser. I can upload files in that website. I have configured database correctly. Now, I have uploaded the following php file there having the code as follows:

```
<?php

    require_once('connection.php');

    $sql = 'SELECT date FROM Khatams';
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $khatam_dates = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $khatam_dates[] = $row['date'];
        }
    } else {
        //echo "0 results";
    }

    echo json_encode($khatam_dates, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    $conn->close();

?>
```

and I can access this file from the browser directly and get the json object as I expect. But when I send a GET request by Java with the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + file);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line, result;

try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
result = stringBuilder.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

I get the following response: ( I formatted it ; was unformatted dump string )

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            function toNumbers(d){
                var e=[];
                d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});
                return e
            }
            function toHex(){
                for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)
                e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);
                return e.toLowerCase()
            }

            var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("c32982e0cee9e5da81856753a7aef5ed");
            document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";
            expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT;
            path="/";
            document.cookie="referer="+escape(document.referer);
            location.href="http://ashubuntu.byethost9.com/fetch_khatam_dates.php?ckattempt=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>
            This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support
        <noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the cause of this type of response? I am particularly interested in the following code fragment:

```
<noscript>
    This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support
<noscript>
```

Comment: How did you solve your issue?
I am also facing the same... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062974/android-multipart-file-upload-using-httpurlconnection-400-bad-request-error

can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the hosting is setting some sort of tracking cookie before redirecting you to your actual page.

<s>Try accessing `http://ashubuntu.byethost9.com/fetch_khatam_dates.php?ckattempt=1` from Java to see if you can work around it this way.</s>

**Edit:** looks like the `?ckattempt=1` part of URL in your posted page source is there to count number of attempts to redirect to check whether the cookie is indeed set.

You're probably out of luck - this is the price you pay for using the free hosting. Only way I can think of is making the site believe you have the cookie set (I'm not sure how this would be done, you'd have to make Java send a plausible-looking cookie of the correct name in the HTTP header).

Comment: There is nothing more expensive than something that is free. This is relatively harmless in its current state as far as I can see; perhaps tomorrow the first banner is going to be added, and possibly some javascript malware.

Comment: change free hosting by another hosting, e.g. a paid hosting