# Android Multipart File Upload using HttpURLConnection - 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: java, android, file-upload, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

I am trying to write a generic code to upload files to any server (Multipart POST).

I have tried different headers and request types in my code and various stackoverflow solutions, but still not able to upload any file.

I keep getting following HTML message as response:
**400 BAD Request**

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("0a569f28135dfc293e0b189974d6ae3d");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/uploadServer.php?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I write a generic code to upload files to servers in Android?

**Android Code:**

```
private int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath, String serverURL) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadFile.... File->"+selectedFilePath+"   to   Server->"+serverURL);
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection conn;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        Log.d(TAG, fileName);
        if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
            // TODO no file exists
            Log.i(TAG, selectedFile+" not exists");
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(serverURL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy            
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile", fileName);
                conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    Log.i(TAG,"while..");
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                conn.connect();

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage().toString();

                Log.i(TAG, "HTTP Response is : "  + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                DataInputStream inStream;
                String str="";
                String response="";
                try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "SOF Server Response" + str);
                        response=str;
                    }
                    inStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ioex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "SOF error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }
                conn.disconnect();
                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

                if(serverResponseCode == 201){
                    Log.e(TAG,"*** SERVER RESPONSE: 201"+response);
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "UL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception : "+ e.getMessage());
            }

            return serverResponseCode; 
        }
```

**PHP code for testing file upload:**

```
<?php 

$target_path = "uploads/"; 

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you posting that <html>?

Comment: I am not posting it, it is coming automatically from somewhere :(

Comment: `name=\"file\"` AND `['uploadedfile']`. should match. They dont.

Comment: Please check message in the html

Comment: Which message? Name it! Quote it!

Comment: I will try that again, i did match them, but it was not working

Comment: Is that html that what you get in `String response` ? Looks impossible to mee. Especialy because you hve bad request.

Comment: In the html response, it is coming JavaScript should be enabled

Comment: Yes.. it get this in my response

Comment: To what kind of webserver are you posting?

Comment: Hosted on a free hosting servers

Comment: You have no error checking at all in that php script. Add it. But first remove all code and just echo some strings. Check if you get tose strings in the response string.

Comment: PHP code is just what I have posted. It is also working if I upload files using HTML form. So it's working for me. I can see uploaded files in uploads folder.

Comment: So then why do you have a bad request? Because of your bad request the php script crashes. You should do the test.

Comment: I did.. for two days... Not sure what is the issue. Hence posted this question ;)

Comment: Are you going to do the test i suggested or not?

Comment: I have tested with error checks... I used PHP file upload example from tutorials point and that also was not uploading any file from Android. Html form upload works.

Comment: I have also used w3school sample as well

Answer (score 1):

I manage to test my code successfully.
It seems the issue was with the free hosting site.
I now created a servlet and tested locally on my machine and I uploaded it to AWS and tested via the device. Both ways, I was able to upload my file from Android.